# Gazebo spawn_model hangs (wrong ros namespace)

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, spawn-model, xml, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have a problem with Gazebo. When I try to launch the model of a robot, I get the following message: loading xml from ros parameter model, but I never get to see the robot in the simulator. The funny thing is that yesterday it loaded the model correctly. Also, when I try to launch some model of Gazebo (a table or something simple) I get the same message and I still see nothing. So, I think that it's not a problem of my model.

Where is the problem? Thanks in advance!

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40587/gazebo-spawn_model-hangs-(wrong-ros-namespace)/) by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-08-05

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-08-05**:
With roswtf I get the following error:
ERROR Communication with [/empty_world_server] raised an error:
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /empty_world_server->/empty_world_server (/clock)

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-08-06**:
With roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world_paused.launch I dont have this problem... Any clue?

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2012-08-06**:
I have the same problem on a machine with ubuntu ludid and latest fuerte from debs.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-07**:
Hi g.sterido, can you update the title of this question to something more specific, e.g. "Gazebo spawn_model hangs (wrong ros namespace)" or similar?  Thanks.

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-08-07**:
Title updated! Thanks for the advice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

for a reason that I do not really understand, it helps to name the node "gazebo" instead of "empty_world_server". I changed that after comparing empty_world.launch and empty_world_paused.launch!

Best

Georg

---

Originally posted by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) with karma: 328 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-08-06**:
Thanks! That works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A recent fix to pass through command line arguments to the ros node initialized within gazebo exposes this problem; by correctly namespacing the gazebo node with the name declared in the launch script.  The `spawn_model` script defaults to look for gazebo services under `/gazebo/` namespace, and thus fails and the gazebo node operating under `/empty_world_server/(spawn_urdf_model, etc.)`.

The fix you suggested above is valid.  Alternatively, one could also pass the additional commandline argument of `gazebo_namespace` to the `spawn_model` script, e.g.

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -gazebo_namespace empty_world_server -...
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2012-08-06**:
Thanks for the explanation! I would suggest to modify the standard world files in gazebo_worlds to be consistent.Best,

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-06**:
@greg thanks for the suggestion, they should all be consistent by 1.6.13. though in 1.6.12, one of them is still broken (empty_world_throttled.launch).

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-08-06**:
Thanks! I thought that my computer was going crazy. Regards

**Comment by [NickVT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2706/nickvt/) on 2012-08-07**:
These extra arguments can be put like this no?

I still don't see anything on my screen...

**Comment by [NickVT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2706/nickvt/) on 2012-08-07**:
I can't change the name to gazebo, since I have already a node like that:

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-07**:
@NickVT  you should remove "-gazebo_namespace youbot_gazebo_model" from your "spawn_model" node since your gazebo node is already namespaced under the default namespace that spawn_model looks for (i.e. "/gazebo").

**Comment by [NickVT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2706/nickvt/) on 2012-08-08**:
Hi John,  without the namespace was the original situation: but Gazebo doesn't come up, there are no errors:  spawn status:   successfully spawned model
[youbot_gazebo_model-3] process has finished cleanly
Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
Starting to spin physics dynamic...